# Swiftmail Not Sending, But no errors

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I have been using SwiftMailer for a long time now, in fact everything I do with emails uses Swiftmailer (http://swiftmailer.org/) However I am caught short this time.  I am doing everything the same as I have done before, but for some reason I am getting now errors, and no email.

Here is the code, with domain and passwords removed:

```
require_once(ROOT."/inc/php/swiftmail/swift_required.php");

//Set up the swiftmail class to internal SMTP server.
$transport  = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('localhost', 25)->setUsername('no-reply@*******.com')->setPassword('********');
$mailer     = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
```

Then, to send the email after I have the string `$htmlMail`:

```
 $swiftEmailMessage = Swift_Message::newInstance("Booking")
        ->setFrom(array('no-reply@*******.com' => 'Mailer'))
        ->setTo($emailTo)
        ->setBody($htmlMail,'text/html');
    $mailResult = $mailer->send($swiftEmailMessage,$failures);
     if ($failures)
    {
        echo "<b>Failures:</b>";
        print_r($failures);
    } else {
        echo "Sent Message to $emailTo<br><br><pre>";
        var_dump($mailResult);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
```

Output is positive, with no error messages whatsoever:

`Sent Message to ****@yahoo.com
int(1)`

However no matter what email address I have tried, It doesnt work.  I have even upgraded my swiftmail, to the latest one 5.0.1.  I get no errors.  If I change the $transport variable's instance to the IP, I get an error.  I have tried changing it to smtp.domain.com as well, but that makes no difference.  I have set up the email address in the control panel of the server.  no-reply@domain.com does exist.  And I have copy and pasted the password over as well so I do not have the wrong password.

What could be wrong?  Why am I not getting any emails at all?

**edit**
Alright for somereason, I am getting an email now.  As far as I know nothing has changed except it's 24 hours later.  However I can recieve my email with Yahoo, but nothing else.  Why is that!!!

**FIXED**
Even though it was sending to YAHOO, I read this page: http://www.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=81374

And it suggested using the SMTP server instead as a lot of servers black list mail that comes from 'Localhost'.  So I changed it the correct SMTP mail server for this domain, and it works!! Hooray!

Comment: swiftmailer's job is done when the email is handed over to the specified SMTP server. after that, swiftmailer is not involved AT ALL in the system. you need to check the mail server's logs to see what happens after that.

Comment: 1st port of call is the mail server log.

Comment: Thanks, I will check them.

Comment: Had the same problem as you and acually it was your last point mentioned: Because it came from "localhost" it was blocked by the spam filter on the recepients side.